# What is the difference between Knockout.js and jQuery

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I want to know about the difference between knockout.js and jQuery.

Comment: I have rolled back your edit as it appears to be an entirely different question, thereby invalidating the answer given by Domecraft. Please put your additional query in a separate question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference between knockout.js and jQuery can be found [HERE](https://web.archive.org/web/20160814191003/http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/knockout/FDM8160313-What-is-Knockout.js-and-how-it-is-different-from-jQuery.html), which shows the main differences of how it is different with jQuery.

For example, knockout.js has declarative bindings, which "allows you to bind the elements of UI to the data model in a simple and convenient way."

Furthermore, knockout.js is very extensible, and it implements custom behaviors as new declarative bindings for easy reuse in just a few lines of code.

Knockout.js is also flexible when it comes to integrating it with other libraries and technologies.

The most important difference, though, is that "Knockout.js is focused only on designing scalable and data-driven UI." - Unlike jQuery it is not for animation or event handling.